# Why doesn't 'sudo sh' source profile.d scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I've got an installation of CentOS 7 where /bin/sh is a symbolic link to bash. However they behave differently when using sudo. For example with 'sudo sh':

```
[centos@ip-xx.xx.xx.xx ~]$ sudo sh
sh-4.2# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

With 'sudo bash':

```
[centos@ip-xx.xx.xx.xx ~]$ sudo bash
[root@ip-xx.xx.xx.xx centos]# echo $PATH
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

The extra PATH element comes from a /etc/profile.d/-script. Why isn't it showing up with 'sudo sh'?

Comment: The bash behaviour surprises me.  Do you have a `~/.bashrc` which strangely sources `/etc/profile`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is the .bashrc that sources the /etc/bashrc that then sources the /etc/profile.d/*. I didn't know that it worked like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` sources `/etc/bashrc`, that then sources `/etc/profile.d/*` (but not `/etc/profile`?).  I don't know if this confusing behaviour is specific to Redhat derived systems, or not.

`~/.bashrc` is sourced by bash when run as a non-login shell.  (For when it's run as a login shell, the [bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) suggest you need to make sure `~./bashrc` is sourced manually in your `~/.bash_profile`).

But when you run `sh`, `~/.bashrc` is not sourced.  `sh` does not source anything unless run as a login shell.

One possible way to avoid this confusion is if you prefer `sudo -i`, which runs a login shell.  The shell used is chosen based on the shell of the target user (i.e. `root` by default).